# Lego Mindstorms Software: "Error code: 4"

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming, software

After updating my EV3 Brick's firmware from V1.09E to V1.10E and reinstalling the **Teacher Edition** of the Lego Mindstorms EV3 software (even though I'm not a teacher), I decided to recover my Brick's files by downloading them from my Windows 10.

But when I downloaded one of the projects, the software froze for about 8 seconds, then gave the following errors. But I already know what they mean, so you don't have to worry about this. It looked like this:

[image]

I continued to make attempts to download the project, but every single time, I got the same results. At last, I chose to postpone downloading that project and started to download a different one. And that's when things got strange. I got a bunch of errors like before, but some of them now had "Error code: 4".
Unfortunately, I couldn't get a screenshot of the image at the time, but I do remember that all the program assets had this error while the programs themselves had "Error code: 0". And just like my other situation, no matter how many times I tried to download it, I still got the same results.

Fortunately I got rid of the problem by restarting my computer as well as the EV3 itself and then waiting a few hours before using either device again. Yet I still wonder, what is "Error code: 4"?

Comment: Hi mindstormsboi and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help] in order to familiarize yourself with the guidelines and the structure and the functions of the site :)

Comment: Alright, I've read the tour already, but I might as well read it a second time again

Comment: I'm sorry for assuming you haven't read it, but your badge clearly says you are a new contributor and based on your statement "there wasn't a search bar for questions" in the first version of your question, I assumed you haven't yet found the [help page about searching](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: I did find the tour in my inbox, but I never found the help page. Hopefully, things are clear now.